# Express the vector $b=2i-3j+5j$ in terms of these set of three vectors

Tags: determinant, vectors

The three vectors are:
$$a_1=i+j+k$$
$$a_2=i-j$$
$$a_3=i+j-2k$$

I have been asked to express the vector $b=2i-3j+5j$ in terms of the three vectors above like: $b= \alpha a_1+\beta a_2+\gamma a_3$. However, I cannot seem to be able to do it. If it helps, the set of vectors form an orthogonal set. I suspect that determinants may be involved because that's what the lectures were covering (which is what this problem was set for as part of a problem sheet). I just have no idea how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find the length of the projection of a vector $v$ onto a vector $u$?

Comment: Sotr of. I am a little ropey when it comes to vectors - it involves the dot product doesn't it?

Comment: By the way, I very much doubt that determinants will be involved in any way in this problem. I can't offhand see any way to squeeze them in.

Comment: It does indeed involve the dot product. Why not go review that material and see if you can make progress on your own?

Comment: Could you perhaps give me a clue as to how that might be used?

Comment: Suppose in the plane you want to write vector $v$ as a combination of two orthogonal vectors $a$ and $b$. You'd project $v$ onto each, to get vectors $p$ and $q$ that were multiples of $a$ and $b$, and they'd sum to $v$. If you know the length of the projection on $a$ is, say, $7$, you might say that $p = 7a$, but that'd be wrong in general. What if $a$ is of length $14$? Then $p = \frac{1}{2} a$, right? So you have to take into account both the length of the projection and the length of the vector you're projecting to. Try to see why this *doesn't* work if $a$ and $b$ are not perpendicular.

Comment: $Ofir's answer is a good general approach, but when you know that the given vectors are perpendicular, you can do it faster (i.e., without solving a 3x3 system) using the idea I've suggested.

Comment: John, you are right, you approch take into count the "geometric" propertis while mine is stricly linear algebra method.

Comment: Rob, do you understand that your question is basicly: find $x,y,z$ such that $$(2,-3,5)=x(1,1,1)+y(1,-1,0)+z(1,1,-2).$$

Comment: Yes I understand your answer. I got x=5.5, y=2.5 and z=16. A bit weird, maybe it's right or maybe I went wrong somewhere. Conceptually it's fine though. However, @JohnHughes I am struggling with your response. Could you possibly work through my problem as an example as it may clear the issue up?

Comment: you should get $$x=\frac{8}{6},y=\frac{15}{6},z=-\frac{11}{6}.$$

Comment: How did you get that?

Answer (score 0):

$$b=xa_1+ya_2+za_3=(x+y+z)i+(x-y+z)j+(x-2z)k=2i-3j+5k.$$
Then you have 3 equations with $x,y,z$ from here you should do it.
$$x+y+z=2$$
$$x-y+z=-3$$
$$x-2z=5$$